# Saving / Loading two HashMaps in the same file

Tags: java, bukkit

I would love to know how can I save and load two HashMaps , I have been trying to use my own method but I can't figure anything out, since one is overriding the other !

Here is my Main.class

```
package me.core.UPTest;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin{

public final Sub sub = new Sub(this);

public void onEnable(){
    getLogger().info("Ultimate Plugin is now enabled.");
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(sub, this);
    sub.loadPoints();
    sub.loadCommandUsed
}

public void onDisable(){
    getLogger().info("Ultimate Plugin is now disabled.");
    sub.savePoints();
    sub.saveCommandUsed();
}
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("points")){
        if(args.length == 0){
            player.sendMessage("You have " + sub.points.get(player.getName().toLowerCase()) + " points.");
            return true;

        }else if(args.length > 0){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "Too many arguments.");
            return true;
        }
    }

    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("vote")){
        if(args.length == 0){
            if(sub.commandused.get(player.getName().toLowerCase()) == false){
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Thank you for voting for our server!");
                sub.commandused.put(player.getName().toLowerCase(), true);
                return true;

            }else{
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "You have already voted for our server!");
            }

        }else if(args.length > 0){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "Too many arguments.");
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Here is my Sub.class

```
package me.core.UPTest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Sub {

private Main plugin;

public Sub(Main plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

private HashMap<String, Integer> points = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private HashMap<String, Boolean> commandused = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

public void loadPoints(){
    for (String str : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(true)) {
        int p = plugin.getConfig().getInt(str);
        points.put(str, p);
    }
    plugin.saveConfig();
}

public void savePoints(){
    for (Entry<String, Integer> pointstostore : points.entrySet()) {
        plugin.getConfig().set(pointstostore.getKey(), pointstostore.getValue());
    }
    plugin.saveConfig();
}

public void loadCommandUsed(){
    for (String str : plugin.getConfig().getKeys(true)){
        boolean p = plugin.getConfig().getBoolean(str);
        commandused.put(str, p);
    }
    plugin.saveConfig();
}

public void saveCommandUsed(){
    for (Entry<String, Boolean> commandusedtostore : commandused.entrySet()){
        plugin.getConfig().set(commandusedtostore.getKey(), commandusedtostore.getValue());
    }
    plugin.saveConfig();
}
    @EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();

    if(points.get(player.getName().toLowerCase()) == null){
        points.put(player.getName().toLowerCase(), 0);
    }
    commandused.put(player.getName().toLowerCase(), false);
}
}
```

As I mentioned in the beginning the maps override each other and I have no idea how to fix that !

Comment: the problem is not in this code but in the classes behind the`plugin`  field and the `plugin.getConfig()` method.  Show them :)

Comment: There here is the complete code :) !

Comment: Are you sure ?? :)

Comment: Yeap that's basically it

Comment: I think the `getConfig()` method is inherited by extending `JavaPlugin` in the `Main` class

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `maps override each other`? Your maps have different values types, how can they be overriden by each other? Do you have any exception?

Comment: No I don't get an exception in the console at all and that weirds me out

Comment: Let me try implementing some commands on it and maybe it can be more easily to solve

Comment: I see from answer of davidhxxx, that you probably refer to the fact that you expect to have both maps saved in configuration, but just the last one of two saved is available, that's it?

Comment: Yes exactly i would except to have both maps in the config file but the last of the two is always saved

Answer (score 0):

1) Why do you write `plugin.saveConfig()` in the load methods ? 
It should not be needed here.

2) `points` and `commandused` maps use the same keys.
I don't understand why you have two maps. One should be enough.

This method

```
public void onDisable(){
    getLogger().info("Ultimate Plugin is now disabled.");
    sub.savePoints();
    sub.saveCommandUsed();
}
```

calls successively `sub.savePoints()` and `sub.saveCommandUsed()`.

So, when you do

```
 plugin.getConfig().set(pointstostore.getKey(), pointstostore.getValue());
```

in `saveCommandUsed()` and

```
plugin.getConfig().set(commandusedtostore.getKey(),commandusedtostore.getValue());
```

in `savePoints()`

The first time, you write the keys-values that you finally stored in the `plugin().getConfig(). 
The second time you overwrite them.

Comment: As i mentioned above i wanted to like have both of the maps saved in the same file differently since one is <String, Integer> and the other is <String, Boolean> so you suggest that i can actually save them both in the same key ?

Comment: If you want store both, you should indeed use for  both the same key. You can save them in a List for example. But why do you need the same information with two different formats ?

Comment: My idea is like in the config.yml for the player to have smth like
player:
  points: (amount)
  commandused: (true / false)